# Delphi Firemonkey TWebbrowser doesn't work on modal dialogs

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8, twebbrowser

I'm using Delphi XE8, FireMonkey, Win32

I'm trying to load a local HTML file in a `TWebBrowser` control that is in a modal dialog. I keep getting an OLE error, even when trying to do something as simple as this in a button click:

```
wbPreview.URL := 'about:blank';
```

> Project WI.exe raised exception class EOleException with message 'Unspecified error'.

I'm thinking that the WebBrowser control doesn't work in a form/dialog that is not the main form of the app.

Does anyone have any insight on this? I've tried placing `TWebBrowser` on the main form, ensured that `TWebbrowser` in the dialog wasn't in a child control (parent is the form), etc.  Nothing works.

Comment: Delphi XE8, fmx, win32. A secondary form with wb and 2 buttons, shown with `Form.ShowModal`, 1st. button sets `wb.URL` to a local `.htm` file, shows ok. 2nd button sets `wb.URL` to 'about:blank', clears the viewport. Alternating buttons, changes the `wb` viewport as expected. No errors, no problems.

Comment: What happens when you set the second form BorderIcons property to [biSystemMenu,biMaximize] ? (no minimize)

Comment: Oh, I didn't save the project. What happens for you, what do you expect to happen? What if you don't remove `biMinimize`.

Comment: I get the error, so at least now I know how to work around it somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not related to whether the form is modal or not, but to whether the form hosting the `TWebBrowser` has default BorderStyle / BorderIcons.

The problem is reported on Embarcadero Quality Portal with [RSP-12640](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12640) and a few others.

The issue is corrected in Delphi 10.1 Berlin